# How to extract json data into variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My script runs fine

```
$.getJSON("../Conseiller/EditerDemandeurs_MenuConseiller",{sIdDdeur: idDdeur}, function (data, status) {
    var result = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(result);
});
```

and when I pass it to `console.log` it gives:

```
Object {rows: Array[1]}
ModalForms.js:10 {"rows":[{"Code_Demandeur":"DD_ANLI000003","Nom_Demandeur":"Anderson","Prenoms_Demandeur":"Liam","UserId":null,"Adresse_Demandeur":"1136 AllEe Gerard Morisset Monarque","Ville":"Saint-Eugène-d'Argentenay (MunicipalitE de)","Province":"QuEbec","CodePostal_Demandeur":"H7A2A7","Tel1_Demandeur":"4180010502          ","Tel2_Demandeur":"5141921617          ","Tel3_Demandeur":null,"Courriel1_Demandeur":"Doiron _Joshua@live.ca","Courriel2_Demandeur":null,"Courriel3_Demandeur":null,"SitMat":"Couple avec enfant","Sexe":"Femme","Date_Naissance_Demandeur":"/Date(-642542400000)/","Revenu_Demandeur":null,"Occupation":"INFIRMIER","Scolarite":"Doctorat","StatutLegal":"REsident permanent","Communaute":"Africaine","SourceInformation":"Accès travail emploi femme","Handicape":false,"Reference":null,"Remarques_Demandeur":null,"ID_Photo":null,"Actif_Inactif":true,"Dte_Saisie":"/Date(1464913323033)/","ID_Utilisateur":1,"Nom_Type_Demandeur":"Principal"}]}
```

My question is how I assign those values to variables?
Using `xx = data.Code_Demandeur` for example gives me "Undefined" error.

Comment: `data.rows[0].Code_Demandeur`

Answer (score 1):

`Code_Demandeur` resides in a `object` which is at `0`th index of the `array`

```js
$.getJSON("../Conseiller/EditerDemandeurs_MenuConseiller", {
  sIdDdeur: idDdeur
}, function(data, status) {
  console.log(data.rows[0].Code_Demandeur);
});
```